# Does attacking difficulty of a block cipher depend on it's block length?

Tags: cryptography

Does attacking difficulty of a block cipher depend on it's block length compared to a substitution cipher?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to ask?  Are you trying to ask if security improves with an increase in block size, or are you asking if block size is the primary security feature of a block cipher.  The answer is no in either case.

Comment: https://sweet32.info/

Answer (score 1):

> Does attacking difficulty of a block cipher depend on its block length

It depends on many things, and block length is part of it. A small block size (64 bit) is [vulnerable](https://sweet32.info/). However, as soon as you reach a reasonable block size, increasing the block size does not really make things more secure. So I wouldn't say a 256 bit block size would be much safer than a 128 bit block size.

Besides block size, another property of block ciphers is they key size. These do not have to be the same. In general, larger keys are more secure, but here also there are diminishing returns when getting sufficiently large.

> compared to a substitution cipher

Block ciphers are usually compared against stream ciphers. I wouldn't say one is more secure than the other.

Even if the cipher itself is perfectly secure, whether the system as a whole is secure depends on whether the cipher is used correctly.